# configurable jframe elements

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have build a digital clock using Swing JFrame, for now the clock is live but it will always show a set of timezone. Is that possible for me to configure the timezone?

I want to set the timezone, name of the label, show/hide the clock.
Is these are possible in executable jar?

Comment: Yes, you can configure a Swing clock, but you have to create the GUI and write the code to make customization possible.

Answer (score 0):

Being a configurable application we have two options

1. Database
2. File

If it's a small application then choosing a database is completely waste of time and memory. We can achieve the same via writing/reading the file.

Again, if we are packing the configuration.properties or reference file along with our runnable jar. It will **fail** because all the files within jar are read only, we cannot write into it.
So the only possibility is to

> **create a temp file either in the same location of the jar or in system
> temp folder**